# How can I change highlight (focused) color of the triangle in a Spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-appcompat, theming

I am currently working on an Android TV app, so the focus color is very important.

I have added some spinners in my layout and I am trying to change the selector color.

Primary/secondary/Accentcolor are not doing anything.

First thing I have is to put the spinners in layout. The top one is the one I am working on, and the bottom one is the default Appcompat

On the top one, I have added a color selector:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/selector"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:padding="0dp" />


<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:padding="0dp" />
```

**selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@color/focused" />
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@color/selected" />
    <item android:state_hovered="true"
        android:drawable="@color/hovered" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/transpa" />
</selector>
```

[image: enter link description here]

This is obvious, but the triangle has been removed due to the new background which is simply a rectangle.

What I would like to achieve is this selection but with my higlight color, and not the default grey:

[image: enter link description here]

And this is current result:

[image: enter link description here]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found the answer :-p

```
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
```

[image]